# Can I pass strings with reserved characters?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try this:

```
db = 'ACS-Sociodemographics(USA,CensusBlockGroups,2018)'
ctx.cursor().execute(f"USE DATABASE {db}")
```

I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 16 unexpected '-'.
```

Is there a recommended way to pass a string with reserved characters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the db name needs to be encased in double quotes. To make life easier, wrap the whole thing in single quotes like so:

```
ctx.cursor().execute(f'USE DATABASE "{db}"')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.